# How to make dynamically created arrays as static?

Tags: c++, static, dynamic-arrays

i want to make dynamically created array as static ,doing which i will be able to access them and modify their values ,
below code runs fine but the function disp() is printing some garbage values,
but i have modified the array in push() ,but the changes are not getting reflected

```
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>
static int t=-1;
int size=5;
template<class X>
class Stk
{
public:
X* arr=new X[size];
X pop()
{
    if(t<=-1)
        return -1;
    X val=arr[t];
    t--;
    cout<<"element popped --->"<<val<<"\n";
    return val;
}
void alloc_mem()
{
    X* newA = new X[size+1];
    std::copy(arr, arr + size, newA);
    delete[] arr;
    arr = newA;
    size++;
}
void push()
{
    X val;
    if(t==size-1)
        alloc_mem();
    cout<<"Enter Value:\n";
    cin>>val;
    t++;
    arr[t]=val;

}
void disp()
{
    if(t<=-1)
    {
        cout<<"Stack is empty\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Stack elements are:\n";
        for(int i=t;i>=0;i--)
        {
            cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
        }
    }
}
};
int main()
{
while(1)
{
    int ch;
    cout<<"---------------\n";
    cout<<"1.PUSH\n2.POP\n3.DISPLAY\n";
    cout<<"------------------\n";
    cin>>ch;
    Stk <int >s;
    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            s.push();
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            if(s.pop()==-1)
                cout<<"Stack is Empty\n";
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            s.disp();
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You create a new `Stk <int >s;` every time round the loop. (And `t` should be a member variable, there's no constructor or destructor, etc, etc)

Comment: by doing so(making t a member variable) i am unable to make it static ,(i want to make it ,so that all modifications to t gets reflected)

Comment: Why don't you simply use `std::vector<X> arr;`, and drop all of the manual memory management (functions such as `alloc_mem()`)?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this smells like a homework assignment on singly linked lists to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments, with every while loop you create a new **Stk** object. So every time you push a value, while loop creates a new Stk object containing some garbage value.

So All you need to do is to move `Stk <int >s;` out of while loop. Then all your changes will be reflected.

And if you want a new object you have to add additional functionality to your program. I made the change in case you still don't get it :

```
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>
static int t=-1;
int size=5;
template<class X>
class Stk
{
public:
X* arr=new X[size];
X pop()
{
    if(t<=-1)
        return -1;
    X val=arr[t];
    t--;
    cout<<"element popped --->"<<val<<"\n";
    return val;
}
void alloc_mem()
{
    X* newA = new X[size+1];
    std::copy(arr, arr + size, newA);
    delete[] arr;
    arr = newA;
    size++;
}
void push()
{
    X val;
    if(t==size-1)
        alloc_mem();
    cout<<"Enter Value:\n";
    cin>>val;
    t++;
    arr[t]=val;

}
void disp()
{
    if(t<=-1)
    {
        cout<<"Stack is empty\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Stack elements are:\n";
        for(int i=t;i>=0;i--)
        {
            cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
        }
    }
}
};
int main()
{
Stk <int >s; // Out of while Loop
while(1)
{
    int ch;
    cout<<"---------------\n";
    cout<<"1.PUSH\n2.POP\n3.DISPLAY\n";
    cout<<"------------------\n";
    cin>>ch;
    
    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            s.push();
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            if(s.pop()==-1)
                cout<<"Stack is Empty\n";
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            s.disp();
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer and comments are correct: you are creating a new instance of `Stk` every time you iterate the loop in main, which is not what you want. Instead, as Suryansh Singh suggests, you should create 1 instance of `Stk` before you enter the `while(1)` loop.

But I thought I would explain a little bit about `static` (the keyword) and 'dynamic' (the concept):

'Dynamic' and `static` are antithetical concepts. 'Dynamic' means your program will change what it does based on circumstances (for example allocating a certain amount of memory for an array based on user input). They keyword `static` has a very specific meaning to the compiler: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-keyword-cpp/ (first hit on DuckDuckGo).  The key thing to understand from the article is that 'When a variable is declared as static, space for it gets allocated for the lifetime of the program.' That is completely opposite to the meaning of the word 'dynamic'.

The best analogy I can come up with is that wanting to dynamically create a `static` resource is sort of like wanting to build a building with an elevator in it that goes to every floor on the building. But, then at some point in the future I might add or remove floors from the building and not change the elevator. Obviously this won't work very well.

Think of your `static` variable `t`. It can change value, just like an elevator can go to different floors. But, `t` can never change it's allotment of memory, much like the elevator can never go to a floor outside the building it is in.

If you want a resource that is shared and can be accessed by different parts of your program, but is also created dynamically, you have many options for achieving this, but your code doesn't require anything like that.

Finally, I am simplifying the meaning of `static` by only discussing it as it applies to variables---which is appropriate to the scope of this question. The meaning is somewhat different when applied to classes or methods.